# join 2 temp tables on different id values (always 249 positions apart)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have two temp tabels like this:

```
     t1                   t2
    id a b c            id a b c    
    1                   250    
    2                   251  
    3                   .
    .                   . 
    .
    250
    251
    .
    .
```

id 250 from t2 is equal with id 1 from t1

id 251 from t2 is equal
with id 2 from t1 and so on.
how can i achieve something like this?

```
select id, a, b, c 
from #t1 
join #t2
on #t1.id - 249 = #t2.id
```

I need this because i need to perform calculations, example:

> (the value from a with the id 250 from t1 - the value from a with id 1
>   from t1 ) * 100 in a new column

Thanks

Comment: did you actually try it? cause it looks correct to me.

Comment: at this point the temp tables are not visible. What i mean by that: I have 1 table and i perform two different queries to create 2 temp tables. From there you know the story. I want to insert the result into another temp table. But isn't the #temp available while i'm in the same sesion? Why am i getting "the multipart identifier t1.id could not be found" ?

Comment: Always 249 positions apart is a very odd relation, that I wouldn't trust after a while when items have been added and removed. Either same id for same item, or have the relation stored somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got it right except for resolving ambiguity in your query. See below syntax

```
select 
  t1.*,
  t2.*,
  (t2.a-t1.a)*100 as result
from #t1 t1
  join #t2 t2
  on t1.id - 249 = t2.id
```

further based on your comment to question

> I have 1 table and i perform two different queries to create 2 temp
>   tables. From there you know the story. I want to insert the result
>   into another temp table.

I'd suggest that instead of creating temp tables used the select queries as inner queries in join like below so that problems with temp tables being invisible at a part is not a hinderance. This saves on memory as well.

```
select 
  t1.*,
  t2.*,
  (t2.a-t1.a)*100 as result
from 
  (
    select id,a,b,c from orig_table 
    --  where ....
   ) t1
  join 
  (
    select id,a,b,c from orig_table 
    --  where ....
   ) t2
  on t1.id - 249 = t2.id
```

**update**

> Do you have any idea how i could write this for 12 different cases?
>   insetead copy pasting the query 12 times. example: case when a like
>   'e1m' or 'e2m', or 'ey1' and so on, 12 in total

Based on asker's comment I'd suggest that following query is a better approach:

```
select 
  id as orig_id,
  a,
  b, 
  case when c like 'c1' then c else Null end as t1c,
  case when c like 'c1' then id-249 else Null end as t1id,
  case when c like 'c2' then c else Null end as t2c,
  case when c like 'c1' then id-249*2 else Null end as t2id
from orig_table
```

Put this as inner query and we can quickly do all calculations over this inner query result set instead of all those joins

demo Sql fiddle link here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7aee/4

Comment: the 2nd query you wrote is exactly what i needed. Thank you. Do you have any idea how i could write this for 12 different cases? insetead copy pasting the query 12 times. example: case when a like 'e1m'  or 'e2m', or 'ey1' and so on, 12 in total.

Comment: also, i don't have the column "id" in the original table. I am creating it with SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY filter1 asc, filter2 asc) AS id . So will the join still work?

Comment: @viorelmunteanu the `ROW_NUMBER()` technique will work for ID. The only caveat is that you should have unique rows based on `filter1,filter2` combination.

Comment: @viorelmunteanu on your earlier comment, there is no better way because  the ids match is not straightforward i.e. not `t1.id=t2.id` but `t1.id-249=t2.id`. Had the id criteria been simple I'd recommend creating `PIVOT` like in this Sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7aee/1

Comment: @viorelmunteanu additionally you can try `case` approach for quicker query .  This will help you create a single table where you can apply operations.See fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7aee/4. I've updated my answer for a demo

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

`select * from #t1 JOIN #t2 ON (#t2.id -249)= #t1.id`

Answer (score 1):

If you have Problem with expireed sessions, please try to use global temps with ##
if that is not working try to manualy create table in the Folder 
YourDB\Databse\System Databases\Tempdb

- **Table variables** (`DECLARE @t TABLE`) are visible only to the connection that creates it, and are deleted when the batch or stored procedure ends.
- **Local temporary tables** (`CREATE TABLE #t`) are visible only to the
  connection that creates it, and are deleted when the connection is
  closed.
- **Global temporary tables** (`CREATE TABLE ##t`) are visible to everyone, 
  and are deleted when all connections that have referenced them have closed.
- **Tempdb permanent tables** (`USE tempdb CREATE TABLE t`) are visible to
  everyone, and are deleted when the server is restarted.